# WPF - ComboBox and DisplayMemberPath

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a simple problem, but I'm unable to figure it out.
I just want to use properly a comboBox over an ObservableCollection of objects showing the value of a property inside it.
Here my XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SavedQueries, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedValuePath="Name"/>
```

and my code:

```
public ObservableCollection<SavedQueryObject> SavedQueries
{
    get
    {
        return _savedQueries;
    }
    set
    {
        _savedQueries = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public HomeViewModel()
{
    LoadQueries();
}
public async void LoadQueries()
{
    Query query = new Query();

    SavedQueries = new ObservableCollection<SavedQueryObject>(query.queryItems());
}
```

The object `SavedQueriesObject` contains 3 proprieties and one of them is called 'Name'.

What I get it's just a list of blank fields. I don't think it's a problem of DataContext because I can bind successfully others properties between model and view.

Additional info:

[image: screen]

Comment: Please also show the code for `SavedQueriesObject`.

Comment: Updated my question. Using 'OnPropertyChanged("SavedQueries") doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Note that it is pointless to use an ObservableCollection when you always replace the SavedQueries collection with a new one. It is also pointless to set `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding. Both settings have no effect.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that the `Name` member of the SavedQueryObject class isn't a public property.

Comment: @Clemens Good idea! Using the code above and a public property `Name`on `SavedQueryObject` I could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: SavedQueryObject is inside a .dll and I didn't find any documentation about it. Anyway Clemens is right. My problem is due that fact 'Name' is not a public property. Thank you!